# Why does my strlen function keep "crashing"?

Tags: c, crash, strlen

I'm trying to write a `strlen` function in C but it doesn't work.

```
int strlen(char*string)
{
    int length=0;
    while(length[string]!='0')
    {
        ++length;
    }
    free(string);
    return length;
}
```

It keeps on crashing no matter how many times I run the compiler. Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: `length[string]`? Just because it works, doesn't mean you should do it!

Comment: Any specific reason you're `free()`ing a string you likely never allocated?

Comment: Why on earth do you have a `free` in there?!?!

Comment: Why do you think that recompiling it would fix a programming error?

Comment: C strings are not terminated with a 0 *digit*, they are terminated with a 0 *byte*.

Comment: (I have never seen a question with so many correct answers/comments that are still incomplete by themselves =^_^=)

Comment: Erroneous `free()` call in code posted by an OP named "malloc" just makes me laugh. sry.

Comment: To add to the list of partial remarks, the name `strlen` is reserved by the C standard. It is undefined behavior to name your own function `strlen`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're probably `free`ing memory the function doesn't own.

For example:

```
strlen("42");
```

would crash because `"42"` is a string literal - you can't modify it.

Note that `'0'` is not the terminating character for a string, but the actual `'0'` character. Use either `'\0'` or `0`.

Remove the `free` and it should work.

I'd also go with the more idiomatic `string[length]`, which, **beware**, is illegal if `string == NULL` - so a null check is in order there.

Comment: Also, `'\0'`. [filler]

Comment: Worse yet, `free()` is probably being applied to memory that was never `malloc`'d or dynamically allocated, a very bad thing to do.

Comment: @sftrabbit true, missed that.

Comment: Wow, thats a fast (and complete) answer.

Comment: I disagree about the “a null check is in order there” part of the answer. The `strlen` function expects a pointer to a zero-terminated string. NULL is only one out of billions of invalid inputs. Testing for this particular invalid input increases boilerplate for little advantage. If what you want is a safe language, then use that (in the implementation of such a language, the NULL test will typically be unnecessary). C with NULL tests everywhere is still unsafe, it's unpleasant to read because it is diluted, and all the checks can even make it slower than the safe, optimizable counterpart.

Answer (score 15):

Your `while` loop should not be comparing against `'0'`.
`'0'` (ascii) is value 48!

Strings don't end with 48.
Strings end with 0.

You should be doing:

```
while(length[string] != 0)
```

*(and all the other answers and comments about other problems in your code are also accurate)*

Comment: There's no reason why `'0'` should be 48. It could be, or it could not be, but that's completely irrelevant.

Comment: @KerrekSB:  Does it matter what '0' is?  It is WRONG, regardless of its value.  (It is *most likely* 48 on most any system this guy is using)

Answer (score 4):

It crashes because I'm guessing the pointer wasn't assigned to any dynamically-allocated object (object created with `malloc`). Just because it's a pointer does not guarantee the fact that it was assigned to something allocated with `malloc` and therefore must be freed. Pointers can point to objects (not necessarily dynamically-allocated ones) and in this case I'm assuming the pointer is set to a string literal (`"Hello World"`). The pointer and its point-ee are allocated on the stack and need not be deleted. `free` is unnecessary in this case because they both will be destructed at the end of their respective scopes. Moreover, anything you create with `malloc` *must* be deleted/freed or you risk a memory leak. And otherwise freeing a pointer not assigned to something made with `malloc` causes undefined behavior which may include a crash.

Answer (score 4):

Never mind, when I got rid of free and '0' it works!!

```
int strlen(char*string)
{
    int length=0;
    while(length[string]!='\0')
    {
        ++length;
    }
    return length;
}
```

Comment: Except it won't return the length of the string.

Comment: No, read the answers, please...

Answer (score 3):

Where does it crash? And why do you free the pointer you receive? That way you are not allowed to do anything with the string after retrieving its length with your function.

Or, if you are calling `free` on a chunk of memory that wasn't allocated using `malloc`, on the stack or whatever, you are in the terrain of undefined behaviour and should be glad it crashes.

Specifically "testing" your method with an invocation like `strlen("test")` will crash your program, as the `char*` wasn't allocated using `malloc`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

```
while(string[length]!=0)
```

Comment: Both are equivalent, but it's a fair suggestion.